# Mac Disk Space disappears with Xamarin Studio

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am running out of space on Macbook pro retina. For Xamarin Studio, I am deleting files and folder to create space so I can run project. Now, there is nothing I can delete to create the space. From last 5-6 days, I am creating 5-6GB space daily. When I start Xamarin Studio and start development , disk space started decrease and left 100-200 MB at the end of the day. It will not free the space event though I clean the project. Don't know how to solve the issue. Help will be really appreciated.
Note: I am working on PCL project.

Comment: How much of space do you have in the start?

Comment: Today morning, I have around 6 GB of space. Now it's showing 2MB. When restart the machine, it show 1.4GB but space automatically decrease to 300 MB without doing anything. Someone has similar kind of problem. But haven't found any solution. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/79105/mac-disk-space-disappears-with-xamarin-studio

Comment: You have multiple options left:

- Check through the Android SDK Manager if there are Android versions installed you do not need and remove them
- Remove obj and bin folders for projects you are not working on
- Clear packages folder for projects you are not working on

Use a disc tool to check what consumes a lot of space on your disc in general.

Comment: Its preferred to have at least 15% of disk size as free space.

Comment: I am building cross platform App so need both iOS and Android SDK. After installing Android SDK and xCode, I have around 30GB for space free. Only one instance of project is running. But I am running out of space. Project folder is showing around 700 MB. I haven't faced low space issue before installing the Xamarin Studio.

Comment: Event though I create space around 5-6 GB, It will occupy by the Xamarin Studio and at the end of the day, it's around 100-200 MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also having the same problem previously. When we build project, there is many temporary files is created. Running Clean project will not help on decreasing the amount of space used.
What I did is download [CleanMyMac](http://cleanmymac.com/) and use it to scan and remove those unwanted files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My issue was, even though I clean the data and create space, Xamarin Studio occupy it and there is no space to run the project. I want to know where Xamarin Studio writing the cached files which were not cleared by cleaning the project from Xamarin Studio.

Comment: I'm not sure on the exact path. But you should be able to review the list of files after you scan with CleanMyMac. Also, I notice the temporary files will also  created after I build native obj-c codes with xcode. So not only xamarin studio having this issues.